# Hilbert's solution of Waring's problem

Tags: nt.number-theory

What actually is the strategy of Hilbert's method of solution to Waring's problem? I do not read German, so I do not understand what he says. But I was told that it is different from the Hardy Littlewood circle method.

Comment: See [MR0414510 (54 #2611)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=414510). Ellison, W. J. *[Waring's problem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317482)*. Amer. Math. Monthly **78** (1971), no. 1, 10–36.

Comment: That's great, thank you!

Comment: There is also Paul Pollack's number theory book, which has a presentation that may be accessible.  Gerhard "Is Still Reading The Chapter" Paseman, 2010.10.22.